# Non-script workaround for Webkit's table cell's rowspan issue

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, html-table

Is there any known non-script workaround to Chrome/webkit issue related to cell **rowspan** that is higher than all non spanned rows combined? Because Chrome doesn't distribute sibling rows evenly but rather sizes the last one to fill the remaining space.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/LRXJx/3/) in different browsers and you'll see results as seen on below images.

#### Column spanning works as expected

Mind that column spanning works as expected. All columns are expanded to accommodate the widest spanned column. If other cells had even width they're also evenly expanded, but if they didn't have width set they expand accordingly to their content (rendering as usual).

### Example screenshots

Outer border shows table border, while inner borders show cell borders. For display reasons I didn't collapse borders so each individual element's border is separate from others.

#### As displayed in Internet Explorer (surprisingly) and Firefox:

[image: Even row distribution]

#### As displayed in Chrome (or other webkit browser):

[image: Uneven row distribution]

### Additional observation of large `rowspan` value

In my example there are 4 rows and last cell in the first row spans all four of them. If I'd change the value to grater than 4, webkit actually would render the nonexisting fifth row without any cells. So instead of expanding the fourth row to take all remaining space that would be the case with fifth non-existing row. This is how the result looks like in Chrome (bot not in any other browser):

[image: Additional non-existing row]

Answer (score 0):

The first Idea when reading this, is to do it like that:

```
<table class="details"><tr><td  >First col</td></tr>
            <tr><td >First col</td></tr>
    <tr><td >First col</td></tr>
    <tr><td >First col</td></tr>
    </table>
<td>Kleke</td>
```

And then manage the borders via CSS (if help is neccesarry for doing that leave a comment)

Cheers Felix

EDIT: I just realized that the year that you asked for that is 2012 and not 2013, if you may can present a better e.g. alternative solution please post it.